# Implementing iterative solution of integral equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration, equation, integral

We have an equation similar to the [Fredholm integral equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation) of second kind.

[image]

To solve this equation we have been given an iterative solution that is guaranteed to converge for our specific equation. Now our only problem consists in implementing this iterative prodedure in MATLAB.

For now, the problematic part of our code looks like this:

```
function delta = delta(x,a,P,H,E,c,c0,w)

delt = @(x)delta_a(x,a,P,H,E,c0,w);

for i=1:500
    delt = @(x)delt(x) - 1/E.*integral(@(xi)((c(1)-c(2)*delt(xi))*ms(xi,x,a,P,H,w)),0,a-0.001);  
end
delta=delt;

end
```

`delta_a` is a function of `x`, and represent the initial value of the iteration. `ms` is a function of `x` and `xi`.

As you might see we want `delt` to depend on both `x` (before the integral) and `xi` (inside of the integral) in the iteration. Unfortunately this way of writing the code (with the function handle) does not give us a numerical value, as we wish. We can't either write `delt` as two different functions, one of `x` and one of `xi`, since `xi` is not defined (until `integral` defines it). So, how can we make sure that `delt` depends on `xi` inside of the integral, and still get a numerical value out of the iteration?

Do any of you have any suggestions to how we might solve this?

*Using numerical integration*

*Explanation of the input parameters: x is a vector of numerical values, all the rest are constants. A problem with my code is that the input parameter x is not being used (I guess this means that x is being treated as a symbol).*

Comment: Do you use symbolic or numerical integration?

Comment: @Jan Numerical integration. (Edited my question)

Comment: Maybe `x` is the vector of grid points where your function is to be approximated....?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do a nesting of anonymous functions in MATLAB:

```
f = 

    @(x)2*x

>> ff = @(x) f(f(x))

ff = 

    @(x)f(f(x))

>> ff(2)

ans =

     8

>> f = ff;


>> f(2)

ans =

     8
```

Also it is possible to rebind the pointers to the functions.

Thus, you  can set up your iteration like

```
delta_old = @(x) delta_a(x)
for i=1:500
    delta_new = @(x) delta_old(x) - integral(@(xi),delta_old(xi))
    delta_old = delta_new
end
```

plus the inclusion of your parameters...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem with my code as well as yours is that the function input parameter x is not being used. x is a vector and it has to be used in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider to solve a discretized version of your problem.

Let `K` be the matrix which discretizes your Fredholm kernel `k(t,s)`, e.g.

```
   K(i,j) = int_a^b K(x_i, s) l_j(s) ds
```

where `l_j(s)` is, for instance, the j-th [lagrange interpolant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) associated to the interpolation nodes `(x_i) = x_1,x_2,...,x_n`.

Then, solving your Picard iterations is as simple as doing

```
  phi_n+1 = f + K*phi_n
```

i.e.

```
  for i = 1:N   
       phi = f + K*phi
  end
```

where `phi_n` and `f` are the nodal values of `phi` and `f` on the `(x_i)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand what you are getting at but could you extend your explanation of l_j(s)? Especially "for instance, the j-th lagrange interpolant..."